# Ansible: to get specific lines from stdout_lines of ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I would like to print specific lines form stdout_lines from ansible playbook with string e.g "systemd". Could you please someone help me on this ?

Comment: Specify specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`select` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#select) is a way of applying an existing test, such as the [`search` test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) to a list of items, allowing through only those items which pass the test's criteria; thus:

```yaml
- shell: |
     for i in alpha system beta; do
       echo "${i}d"
     done
  register: bob
- debug:
    msg: '{{ bob.stdout_lines | select("search", "systemd") | list }}'
```

You need that final `| list` on the end because `select` and its `map` friend produce python generators, and thus need a terminating operation, either `first` or `list` or `length` to cause them to actually do work

Comment: Hi Mdaniel, You answer helped me perfectly. Ansible should document this example.Thanks lot